# how to get current physicalPath site using appcmd.exe

Tags: iis, windows-command-prompt, appcmd

we want get current physicalPath of the site using appcmd.exe.

how to identify physicalPath of site via site name or app pool name.

Comment: Any reason you are not using PowerShell for this kind of stuff? Much easier.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf i want showing result in a table of the sites with directory in webpage.

Comment: in PowerShell you could do something like `Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites\ | Select Name, physicalPath |  ConvertTo-Html -Title "My sites" | Set-Content -Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve the problem with the following command:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list app /site.name:"example.com" /path:"/" /xml | %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list vdir /in /text:physicalPath
```